# Restify.js (Connect/Express) middleware ignoring call to next() within promise callback

Tags: node.js, express, connect, q, restify

So. I'm experiencing some quirks when attempting to implement some basic middleware for a Restify.js application I'm building with specific regard to `next()` and promise callbacks.

To express the problem in a generic form:

```
  var server = restify.createServer({
    name: config.name
  });
```

Promise resolves:

```
  server.use(function checkAcl(req, res, next) {
    // Promise is resolved
    var promise = function () {
      var deferred = require('q').defer();
      deferred.resolve();
      return deferred.promise;
    }

    promise()
      .then(function () {
        next(); // doesn't get 'called', no response sent, connection eventually times out
      }, function () {
        res.send(new restify.NotAuthorizedError());
      });
  });
  server.use(restify.bodyParser());

  ...
```

Promise is rejected

```
  server.use(function checkAcl(req, res, next) {
    // Promise is rejected
    var promise = function () {
      var deferred = require('q').defer();
      deferred.reject();
      return deferred.promise;
    }

    promise()
      .then(function () {
        next(); 
      }, function () {
        res.send(new restify.NotAuthorizedError()); // this works fine
      });
    }
  });

  server.use(restify.bodyParser());      

  ...
```

Am I doing anything obviously wrong?  Any insight? It certainly seems to been related to the promise callbacks, are they somehow suppressing the call to `next()`?

Comment: Which of your `console.log`s happen?

Comment: ok, so in the example above. ACL passes `(allowed === true)` so to answer your question directly: AuthToken Verified, Found User, ACL Passed

Comment: updated the question with a more generic representation of the problem  (see bottom).

Comment: what if you replace the promise code with `setTimeout(function () { next(); }, 0);`? Also try just calling `next()` directly.

Comment: BTW you can replace those lines with `var promise = Q.resolve()` and `var promise = Q.reject()` then replace `promise()` with `promise`.

Comment: The problem seems related to my use of `      server.use(restify.bodyParser());` (which I had neglected to mention).  Changing the order of the `server.use()` declarations seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the `restify.bodyParser()` middleware BEFORE the custom middleware resolves the issue.

n.b:

```
  // Add bodyParser() to the stack before the custom middleware
  server.use(restify.bodyParser()); 

  server.use(function checkAcl(req, res, next) {
    // Promise is resolved
    var promise = function () {
      var deferred = require('q').defer();
      deferred.resolve();
      return deferred.promise;
    }

    promise()
      .then(function () {
        next(); // next() now behaves as expected.
      }, function () {
        res.send(new restify.NotAuthorizedError());
      });
  });
  ...
```

Further to that, I eventually happened upon [this Github issue](https://github.com/mcavage/node-restify/issues/287) describing the issue along with another  possible solution if the order of your middleware matters (which it probably does).

> mcavage: Pretty sure this is actually node that's biting you (as in your data is emitted to nowhere). Try this:

```
  var server.createServer();
  server.pre(restify.pre.pause());
  ...
```